# compare two IEnumerable and delete/insert based on the comparison result

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ienumerable

I have to compare the IEnumerable data from UI and the IEnumerable data from SQL Server 2008 and have to insert/update the new elements from UI to DB and delete the elements from DB based on UI data.

I am having Distribution_X_ListType table in DB as:

```
DistributionID ListTypeID EmployeeNumber DepartmentID LocationID
1              2          84528          NULL         NULL 
1              3          NULL           8051         NULL
1              5          NULL           NULL         319
```

I am having an interface in a project as follows:

```
public interface IDistributionList : IEntity
    {
        string Name { get; set; }
        bool ActiveFlag { get; set; }
        ...........................
        ...........................
        IEnumerable<IDistributionListType> ListTypes { get; set; }        
    }
```

The another interface is:

```
public interface IDistributionListType
{
    int? DistributionID { get; set; }
    int ListTypeID { get; set; }
    int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    int DepartmentID { get; set; }
    int LocationID { get; set; }
}
```

In another project I am having Save function as follows:

```
public int Save(IDistributionList distributionList)
        {
            SqlDataReader reader = null;            
            int rowsaffected = 0;
            try
            {
                sqlcommand = new SqlCommand("spGetDistributionListTypeByID", con);  //spGetDistributionListTypeByID - This SP returns all the members from Distribution_X_ListType table for the given distribution ID
                sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Distribution_ID", distributionList.ID);

                reader = sqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                      ????Value Should be stored in an IDistributionListType variable,say IDistributionListTypeFromDB 
                }
                ????IDistributionListType from function parameter(Lets say from UI) should be compared with the above IDistributionListTypeFromDB data.
                ????Insert/Delete should be done in DB by comparing the data.
             }
         }
```

Let the value of IDistributionListType from UI:

```
DistributionID ListTypeID EmployeeNumber DepartmentID LocationID
1              2          84528          NULL         NULL 
1              5          NULL           NULL         64
```

Let the value of IDistributionListType from DB:

```
DistributionID ListTypeID EmployeeNumber DepartmentID LocationID
1              2          84528          NULL         NULL 
1              3          NULL           8051         NULL
1              5          NULL           NULL         319
```

I need to update the DB with the data from UI. I am having two more SPs as :

```
spInsertUpdateDistributionListType - Insert/Update Distribution_X_ListType table  based on DistributionID and listtypeID
spDeleteDistributionListType - Delete Distribution_X_ListType table based on DistributionID and listtypeID
```

I don't know how to code in ???? areas(mentioned in .net code). Anybody please helpout. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use an O/R mapper like [Entity Framework](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/) and it will deal with this for you.